# Find a pattern and replace the whole line & find a pattern and insert after

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

Question 1:

Pattern:

```
test_$(whoami)
```

Variable:

```
var1=$(pwd)
```

I want to find the pattern and replace the whole line with `var1`

```
sed -i "s/.*test_$(whoami).*/$var1/" test.txt
```

It gives me sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'

Question 2.

Pattern:

```
#####Insert here#####
```

Content to be insert:  include $var1/file_$(whoami).txt

I want to find the line with the pattern(Fully match), and insert the content one line after

```
sed -i "s/#####Insert here#####/include $var1/file_$(whoami).txt" test.txt
```

Doesn't work either

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Re Question **1**.  Use a different regex delimiter:

```
sed -i.bak "s~^.*test_$(whoami).*$~$var1~" test.txt
```

since `$var1` can contain `/`

Answer (score 0):

Question 1.
It seems *$var1* contains a character interpreted as a **sed** delimiter, namely: '/'.

In a *substitute* command, after the third delimiter, **sed** expects an occurrence number, and you may be providing text.

Example, if:

```
var1="~/myDirectory"
```

Then this produces a **sed** command with too many delimiters:

```
sed -i 's/.*test_$(whoami).*/~/myDirectory/"
```

You should use a different delimiter character such as ~, #, !, ?, &, | ... one which is not present in your regexp.
**Sed** will automatically recognize the delimiter character after the *substitute* command and enable you to use the '/' character *in* your regexp:

```
sed "s#~/toto#~/tata#"
```

If you have difficulties finding a character that is not present in your regexp, you can use a non-printable character which is unlikely to exist in your pattern. For example, if your shell is **bash**:

```
$ echo '/~#' | sed s$'\001''/~#'$'\001''!?\&'$'\001''g'
```

In this example, **bash** replaces `$'\001'` with the character that has the octal value 001 - in ASCII it's the SOH character (start of heading).

Since such characters are control/non-printable characters, it's doubtful that they will exist in the pattern. Unless, that is, you are doing something weird like modifying binary files - or Unicode files without the proper locale settings.

Question 2.
You may be looking for **sed**'s append function ('a'):

```
 sed -i "/#####Insert here#####/ a include $var1/file_$(whoami).txt"  test.txt
```